# React Browser Router Module not found?

Tags: reactjs, npm, compiler-errors, react-router

I've been working on a react website and I'm trying to import the BrowserRouter module and nothing is showing up... Here's a pic.. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Link to my IDE :

[image]

Comment: version of react-router-dom?

Comment: @MonicaAcha how would I go about checking that info? still kind of new to react. thanks :)

Comment: Look into package.json file if you have installed using npm

Comment: @MonicaAcha I see version 16.8.3 and it says react-dom

Comment: NVM.. Just installed it now! Thanks for your help @MonicaAcha

Comment: I am posting it as an answer so that it could help somebody ! Kindly accept my answer

Comment: So what I did to fix the problem was install 'react-router-dom' by using the (npm install --save react-router-dom) command . I didn't see my problem at first because I forgot to install the dependency. After installing, the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest version of `react-router-dom`. Also update your `react`, `reactDOM` versions to avoid certain compilation errors.